# Select distinct rows by count in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

I have a table `hastags`

```
id|tweet_id|  tag   |time
1   1       hell   
2   2       hellyeah    
3   3       hell
4   4       stackoverflow
5   5       hell   
6   6       hellyeah    
7   7       bellrings
8   7       nomorehell
8   7       nomorehell
```

I want to select the count of *most used* `tags` above a *specific time*.
Now if i limit my query to 3 rows i should get

```
|tag    | count|
hell        3
hellyeah    2
nomorehell  2
```

How can i achieve this any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose `2014-12-29` as an example of a specific time

```
select tag, 
       sum(`time` > '2014-12-29') as sum_greater,
       sum(`time` < '2014-12-29') as sum_smaller
from hashtags
group by tag
order by sum_greater desc, sum_smaller desc
limit 3
```

Comment: now if i want to combine to specific times means..........................      `select tag, count(*) as count
from hashtags
where `time` > '2014-12-29'
group by tag
order by count desc
limit 3`    and `select tag, count(*) as count
from hashtags
where `time` > '2013-12-29' AND `time` < '2014-12-29'
group by tag
order by count desc
limit 3` THEN how to do ?

Comment: I updated the answer. Sum up the conditions. But you have to choose which column you want to use for sorting first.

Comment: will the 1st and 2nd will have equal no of rows ?

Comment: Yes, equal rows. It is one query, not two.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tag, count(*) as anz FROM hastags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY anz DESC
```

Comment: now if i want to combine to specific times means..........................      `select tag, count(*) as count
from hashtags
where `time` > '2014-12-29'
group by tag
order by count desc
limit 3`    and `select tag, count(*) as count
from hashtags
where `time` > '2013-12-29' AND `time` < '2014-12-29'
group by tag
order by count desc
limit 3` THEN how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering start time and end time is given then this query will work.

```
SELECT tag, count(tag) FROM hastags where (start <= end and :time >= start and :time <= end) or
  (end < start and (:time <= end or :time >= start)) GROUP BY tag;
```